# SEO and buying expiring or dropped domain

Tags: seo, domains, domain-registration

Does it make any difference for SEO benefits to buy dropped and already available domains other than backorder domains that are expiring soon?

I heard somewhere that whois gets deleted after being dropped. But I didn't find any confirmation if it's true or not.

Anybody can tell me if there are benefits of one against the other, if yes what?

Comment: What is your intention to get expired domains, is it for backlink or building your own presence there?

Comment: Both. I want to create a little PNB, with content, updating term from time to time. And give a backlink to my business site. Also those sites will be facing as part od my business. So the are not strictly for backlink, but also if they will have a good SERP will drive clients to me, even if they don't clifk my mail business site. Of course getting backlinks to my main sites is important to drive there "power". So to answer ur question is "both", but mainly backlink

Comment: Why bring up that whois gets deleted?  Why would that matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, these strategies fall in grey SEO technique.

Having said that, if you prove to Google about relevancy and if you may have a proper linking strategy then you may be fine.

Slowly these strategies are coming to an end but still works if planned well.

In a long run, the best recommendation would be to have one primary website with the best content and better authority.

But if your risk appetite is higher then you may consider above approach.

Comment: How to increase the authority without back links?

Comment: There are many ways you boost website authority like: building rich content in your website which people would live to read, share and link. If you will build rich experience it will last longer rather than having grey strategy which may lead to a penalty. A simple example i can give you is, just have a very powerful well-researched blog and share on social media and you will see a significant change in your traffic and authority in general. There are many more strategies.

Comment: Other question. What do you mean with "planned well"? Do u have some suggestions or a tutorial/guidelines Trustworthy?

Comment: Planned well meaning, there is a fine line between white hat SEO and grey. So, even expired domain can be used to the maximum provided the domain got good history the content which you will load will be also related, the link balance on the page etc. These strategies don't fall under the best practice so more than anything SEO knowledge, in general, is very important.

Comment: Thank you. Coming back to my original question. Is it better to buy an expired domain and release or catch it in back order when it's already expiring? Any difference for SEO?

Comment: Google does maintain the ranking juice (backlink) for a good amount of time, so unless the website might be offline for way too long, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Wayback history of that domain name and check that if that domain hasn't been used for any other niche such as any spammed niche. If it is clean, then check that how many links on that domain. What are the referring domains coming to that domains wrt how many links it have if the number is fluctuation ing by large no? Then leave that domain else to buy, it.

After checking these points of the domain crosses these checks then you can buy it, and you can use it for link benefits.